# If ACID properties are well defined why do we have/accept different transaction levels?

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, isolation-level, acid

I am confused about the ACID properties of a transaction.
According to my understanding:
A transaction **MUST** be ACID compliant. It is the ACID that ensures that a series of statements is indeed a transaction. So far ok.
Now there are various Isolation Levels (I leave out the READ-UNCOMMITED since it is a non-transactional mode altogether): READ-COMMITED, READ-REPEATABLE and SERIALIZABLE
Each of these levels offer different degrees of isolation, in my understanding also consistency.
So what I can not understand is the following:
If the various isolation level offer different levels of the pre-requisite ACID properties how can they be valid/acceptable isolation levels?
Or is the SQL definition of what is a transaction so relaxed/non-formal/non-strict that these differences came up? I could not find any SQL standard document to read and see what is the actual definition

Answer (score 0):

ACID is great, ACID is desirable, ACID is awesome.

But ACID is standard. A standard existence does not automatically makes make all implementer players adherent.

A RDBMS is ACID compliant if it provided ACID behavior in any way. Not every DMBS is ACID compliant (MySQL was NOT, until recently).

ACID is the ideal world. Isolation Levels are the real world.

Comment: If it is a standard how different degrees of implementation are acceptable?Is it a loose standard?Where are these definitions?

Comment: @Jim Forget the context for a minute. If a say my software supports standard ABC, does it mean it ONLY operates according to standard ABC flows and definitions?

Comment: But it should adhere to anything defined using a **MUST** at least right?Same as an RFC I imagine

Answer (score 0):

> why do we have/accept different transaction levels?

Theorically each transaction should to execute in isolation (for achieving the I of ACID properties) but in practice this has not much sense. It's all about a performance issue. A high concurrency application's database could not execute properly in this way.

The idea is to achieve balancing between isolation and performance. When the isolation level is decreased (e.g. COMMITTED READ that generally is the default isolation level) some kind of problems can appear: lost updates, non-repetable read, phantom read. Usually this risk is acceptable and it can be also controlled rising the isolation level only at certain transactions.

Answer (score 0):

I also find the ACID properties confusing. In my opinion, the properties are not well-defined. The isolation property seems to have been added to be describe a relaxing from the atomicity property. For a "real" transaction (isolation level SERIALIZABLE) only the ACD properties are of interest. These three properties were orgininally proposed by Gray.

See more about this on my blog, "ACID Does Not Make Sense".

http://blog.franslundberg.com/2013/12/acid-does-not-make-sense.html

Comment: Atomicity has to do with all the *writes* of the transaction becoming visible atomically, or not at all.  Isolation has to do with *reads* of a transaction not seeing the writes of *other* transactions, *even if those other transactions have committed*.  Serializable transactions must exhibit a behavior consistent with some one-at-a-time execution.  It is quite possible for transactions to commit atomically and still violate that.  In the narrow case of Strict Two-Phase Locking (S2PL) you are probably correct that Isolation in ACID is redundant, but not if you look at other techniques.